# Coldfusion Encryption/Decryption issue

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I recently did a website for my company using ColdFusion 9. The issue I am having is with the ColdFusion encryption/decryption function. On certain strings that I decrypt I get these weird special characters that show up.

Example:

`MK/_0` <---Encrypted String Outputted

`�#5&z` <---Decrypted String Outputted

I'm not sure why this is happening (and only on certain strings that get decrypted).

Here is the code:

```
<cfset ccNum = decrypt(getCCInfo.CUST_CARDNUMBER,myKey)>
```

Comment: Code samples, please. It's difficult to tell what's wrong without knowing what you are doing. I suspect it is likely an encoding issue.

Comment: Here is my code:

<cfset ccNum = decrypt(getCCInfo.CUST_CARDNUMBER,myKey)>

Comment: I edited your original question to include your code.  You can delete your answer below where you included it.  For future reference, StackOverflow is a Wiki that will allow you or others to go back and edit your questions or answers to improve their quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, well first, I have to point out that by not specifying an encryption algorithm you are using very POOR encryption. So you'll need to fix that.  Second, you should probably be using some encoding to make your crypto storage more reliable.

So try this code.

```
<cfset key = generateSecretKey("AES") />

<!--- Set the ciphertext to a variable. This is the string you will store for later deciphering --->
<cfset cipherText = encrypt(plaintext, key, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "HEX") />

<cfoutput>#cipherText#</cfoutput> 

<!--- Then when you decrypt --->

<cfset decipherText = decrypt(cipherText, key, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "HEX") />

<cfoutput>#decipherText#</cfoutput>
```

The above code will use a strong crypto algorithm and will put the ciphertext into a much easier to store format than the gibberish you showed as an example above. That way when you store it, it will be more reliable when you retrieve it again.

Here is an example of what the string will look like:

```
A51BBB284D6DCCDC17D26FB481584236087C3AB272918E17963BAF749438C06A484922820EDCCD25150732CC5CF8A096
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and thanks for editing my original post. This is the first time Im actually posting on this site but anyway I tried your code and I keep getting this coldfusion error:

"An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input string: '' Can not decode string "testKey!$@".."

Now all I did was add a test key and tired encrypting and decrypting a simple string and I got that error. Is the encryption format in your example different than the one I was using? Again thank you very much for the help.

Comment: An AES key needs to be an exact length. In this case, 128-bit. You can't just throw any string in there.

Comment: To create a test key you can use the generateSecretKeyMethod(). I'll modify my post to include that.