# SagePay V3 Form Integration using CFML - AES Encryption

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, aes, opayo, openbd

I've got through the entire FORM integration successfully except for the encryption.

Version 3 requires AES encryption and I don't understand how to implement this stage.

Previously, the CFML script constructed the crypt field at the end using this:

```
//** call to include file to encrypt
crypt = base64Encode (SimpleXor(stuff,EncryptionPassword));
```

This called the functions file which did the actual work.

The help I need is in creating a new script in the function.cfm file and also what the call should be.

Can anyone help, please?

Cheers

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
<cfscript>

ThisVendorTxCode = "#sfo_id#";

ThisVendorName = "pivotell";

stuff = "VendorTxCode=" & ThisVendorTxCode & "&";

stuff = stuff & "VendorName=" & ThisVendorName & "&";

</cfscript>

<cfset encryptionKey = generateSecretKey( "AES" ) />

//** call to include file to encrypt

<cfset crypt = encrypt(stuff,encryptionKey,"AES","hex") />

<cfoutput>

<form action="https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">

<input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value="3.00">

<input type="hidden" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT">

<input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value="#crypt#">

</form>

</cfoutput>
```

I've truncated the full thing for simplicity.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. As written, your questions is [a bit too broad for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and runs the risk of being closed.  1) What code have you tried so far? 2) What errors have you encountered? 3) Did you search the archives? There are a [few threads on SagePay](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[coldfusion]+sagePay) that might give you a starting point. Also, if there is a public url for that API, it would not hurt to include it above.

Comment: Side note, if you are using ACF, best to include the `[coldfusion]` tag as well, to reach a larger audience.

Comment: Is the code sample here of any use? 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854251/coldfusion-encryption-decryption-issue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854251/coldfusion-encryption-decryption-issue

Comment: This is still too broad. First, please post a link to the API you are using.  We need to know the exact encryption specs you were given. The encryption "key" size, "mode" and whether or not you were provided with a "key" and "iv" value are all relevant bits of information - ones you have not provided ;-) Second, did you read the links above? [One of them specifically mentions SagePage v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390583/encrypt-for-sagepay-forms-using-coldfusion) and without knowing more, I am guessing you may be making some of the same mistakes as in the other thread.

Answer (score 2):

It took me 3 days and 3 nights to figure this out.
Please read page 37 of the [Sage Pay Form Integration and Protocol Guidelines 3.00](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/21086/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_130515.pdf?token=1iz5tNNCvpJ_3AvWD3mXJbKziIVN6SqMBBU96SanyD8).

> **A1.1  The Crypt Field**
>
> 1. The Crypt field should contain all the other transaction information in plain text as Name=Value  fields separated by ‘&’
>      characters.  Ensure that all mandatory fields are present and that
>      there  are no spaces after the ‘&’ character.
> 2. This string should then be encrypted using AES (block size 128-bit) in CBC mode with PKCS#5  padding using the provided password as both
>      the key and initialisation vector and encode the  result in hex
>      (making sure the letters are in upper case).
> 3. Prepend the ‘@’ sign to the beginning of the encoded result.

Together with [the last answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22394464). It should sort it.

> ... Since your password string is not base64 encoded, the resulting key
>   length is too small, ie (12) instead of (16) bytes. ...The solution is
>   to base64 encode it first... Also, the iv parameter should be binary
>
> ```
>   <cfset keyIVBytes = charsetDecode(yourKeyString, "utf-8")>
>   <cfset base64Key = binaryEncode(keyIVBytes, "base64")>
>
>   <cfset result = encrypt(plainString, base64Key,"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex", keyIVBytes)>
> ```

Comment: Welcome to S.O.  While the links above contained the answer, it is better to include a brief summary as well, rather than just links. ["Link only answers" are usually deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) because the answers become meaningless when the links change or break.

Comment: BTW, I did not down vote this, but I suspect it was down voted due to the link only nature of the original answer.